# get latest records in group of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the next table:

[image]

and i want to select only for every group of id the latest record by date

means, that the result will show: row 1 and row 3

how can i do it?

Comment: `select * from (select row_number() over(partition by ..order by.. desc) rn,* from ..) A where rn =1`

Comment: or, with subquery:  `Select * from myTable t where Date = (Select max(Date) from mytable where id = t.id)`

Comment: or WITH TIES  Select Top 1 With Ties * From  YourTable Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order By [Date] Desc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title says "latest" but you specified row 1 & 3.
Switch the MAX to a MIN depending on what you want.

```
   ;WITH cte
        AS
        (SELECT id,MAX([date]) AS [Date] FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID)
    SELECT
        A.*
    FROM
        MyTable A
            INNER JOIN cte B
                ON A.ID  = B.ID
                AND A.[Date] = B.[Date]
                ;
```